# How to know country of the marketplace that was used to download of the instance of an application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to know country of an user, but I don't like to use the Location API. Because it require additional certification and seems strange for my app. I need to know it to enable country's specified features. I check the culture of a phone but it doesn't perfect.

Comment: If you have features specific to a country, it doesn't seem strange for an app to use the Location API.

Comment: It is strange if calculator asks an access to the customer location, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but what about using

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
```

and then give the user an option to change it in the settings?

Comment: I live in Russia but on all my devices I use en-US. And I know people who uses the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

Get the 2 character ISO region (country) code with this:
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName

Comment: It seems to be a solution, but I can't find an information about source of the data which available from this object.